# Could not build wheels for pyarrow - Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, pyarrow

Recently, we've been seeing failures building pyarrow dependencies in our Python 3.9 project. This started about 08:57:01 PM, Oct 5 2021

```
25hCollecting pyarrow 20:58:39 Downloading pyarrow-5.0.0.tar.gz (739 kB) 20:58:39 |
████████████████████████████████| 739 kB 90.7 MB/s 21:00:1425h Installing build dependencies ... 25l- \ | / - \ | / - \ | / - error 21:00:14 ERROR: Command errored out 
with exit status 1: 21:00:14 command: /usr/local/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-
55h74pun/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-
build-env-i45zzwqe/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary 
:none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.16.6; 
python_version<'"'"'3.9'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.4; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' setuptools 
setuptools_scm wheel 21:00:14 cwd: None
```

...

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
21:12:46
```

Before this time, we were building successfully, and we have made no changes to our code.

I do notice that our current jobs are failing on downloading `pyarrow-5.0.0.tar.gz (739 kB)` while the older, successful jobs were downloading `pyarrow-5.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (23.7 MB)`

I am curious Why there was there a change from using a `.whl` file to a `tar.gz` file
 
requirements.txt:

```
boto3
halo
pandas
numpy
pyarrow
s3fs
click
```

How we install:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

I have attached a full output error log on the Pyarrow [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14248)

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using python 3.9.  You are using python 3.10.  Note your install line...

```
command: /usr/local/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-55h74pun/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-i45zzwqe/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.16.6; python_version<'"'"'3.9'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.4; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel
```

In particular I see `python_version<3.9` and `python_version>=3.9`.  Then a little further down:

```
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment
```

Finally, the wheels that are being downloaded are `cp310` wheels.

You can track Python 3.10 support for pyarrow here: [ARROW-14217](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14217)